# Get Remaining row from both common tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables which has data in it. Below are the details.

Table `A`:-  tbl_ipcolo_mast_info -> `42K records`

Table `B`:-  tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump-> `40K records`

Table A consist of all the table B. I want only the other 2k records from table A. How to get it.

Comment: Check about MINUS: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info 
where <PK_COLUMN> in 
  (select <PK_COLUMN> from 
    tbl_ipcolo_mast_info
  minus
  select <PK_COLUMN> from
    tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump)
```

-- update --

According to our comments below, table A and table B both have identical columns, the simple `MINUS` operator can be used to achieve the desired result:

```
select * from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info 
MINUS
select * from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump
```

To check if both the tables have an identical structure, please query on the dictionary view: `USER_TAB_COLS`

Cheers!!

Comment: i am still getting 42k records.

Comment: also, i dont have any primary key in my table

Comment: then what is the criteria to identify that the records in both tables are same?

Comment: i have just did select * into new table and put the table data from A to B.. and after some time i have added more data in A table.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong. There are the same number of columns in table A and table B with the same data type and same order?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MINUS` for that:

```
select *
from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info
minus
select *
from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump;
```

The above assumes that the structure of both tables is **identical**. If they are different you need to explicitly list the matching columns in each SELECT part.

Comment: Yes, due to different columns its giving me `ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns`.  i will update it and check

Comment: @BN Then - as I wrote - you need to list all matching columns in both select statements. As you have not show us the structure of the tables, I don't know the column names

Comment: still, i am getting 42k records even after minus.. why ?

Comment: identical means ? do we need to have Primary key in the table. ?

Answer (score 0):

select column list from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info
minus 
select column list from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2 tables do not have the same columns use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump d
  where <conditions here>
)
```

Replace `<conditions here>` with conditions like:

```
d.columnd1 = t.columnt1 and d.columnd2 = t.columnt2 and ....
```

Or with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t.* 
from tbl_ipcolo_mast_info t left join tbl_ipcolo_mast_info_dump d
on d.columnd1 = t.columnt1 and d.columnd2 = t.columnt2 and ....
where d.columnd1 is null
```